# How to escape a range of wildcards in unix shell script?

Tags: shell-script, quoting, ksh, command-substitution, here-document

I need to execute the following Oracle SQL in unix crontab. The query is as follows:

```
select count(*)
from tbaadm.htd
where cust_id is not null and
pstd_flg = 'Y' and
del_flg = 'N' and
tran_date =  (select db_stat_date-1 from tbaadm.gct) and
REGEXP_LIKE(tran_particular,'[^[:alnum:] ''`~!@#$%^&*-_{};":/.,<>?()]');
```

I have set escape characters before each wildcard, but still I am getting error. So I have written the crontab where I select the count first. But I am getting error again and again. Following are the relevant contents from my crontab:

```
. $HOME/.profile

function dbconstants
{
USER="user"
PASS="password"
MAIL_BODY_PATH="/home/admin/CRONTAB_SHELL/"
MAIL_BODY=$MAIL_BODY_PATH"mail.txt"
}

function checkcount
{
COUNT=`sqlplus -s $USER/$PASS@proddb <<EOF
#connect $USER/$PASS@proddb;
set pagesize 0
SET ESCAPE '\'
select count(*)
from tbaadm.htd
where cust_id is not null and
pstd_flg = 'Y' and
del_flg = 'N' and
tran_date =  (select db_stat_date-1 from tbaadm.gct) and
REGEXP_LIKE(tran_particular,'[^[:alnum:] \'\'\`\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\-\_\{\}\;\"\:\/\.\,\<\>\?\(\)\]\'\)\;
EOF`
echo $COUNT
echo $COUNT | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' |& read -p COUNT1
}
function fetchdetails
{
`sqlplus -s $USER/$PASS@finratna <<EOF >$MAIL_BODY
set feed off pages 0 trimspool on
set pagesize 60
set linesize 9999
set trim on
set head off
SET ESCAPE '\'
alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MM-YYYY';
select tran_date|| '|,' ||tran_id|| '|,' ||part_tran_srl_num|| '|,' ||tran_particular|| '|,' ||REGEXP_REPLACE
(tran_particular,'[^[:alnum:] ''\`~!@#$%^&*-_{};":/.,<>?()]','') reg_par
from tbaadm.htd
where cust_id is not null and
pstd_flg = 'Y' and
del_flg = 'N' and
tran_date =  (select db_stat_date-1 from tbaadm.gct) and
REGEXP_LIKE(tran_particular,'[^[:alnum:] ''\`~!@#$%^&*-_{};":/.,<>?()]');
EOF`
}
function deletefile
{
        rm -f $MAIL_BODY
}

dbconstants
checkcount
if [ "$COUNT" -gt 0 ]
then
fetchdetails
else
echo "Nothing to Worry"
fi

deletefile
```

The error I am getting is:

```
checkcount[13]: ~!@#$%^&*-_{};":/.,<>?()]');:  not found.

Nothing to Worry
```

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates the problem is here:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(tran_particular,'[^[:alnum:] \'\'\`\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\-\_\{\}\;\"\:\/\.\,\<\>\?\(\)\]\'\)\;
                                              ^
```

The shell interprets this backquote as closing the one in `COUNT=`, and tries to run the remaining of the line as a command, `~!@#$%^&*-_{};":/.,<>?()]');`.

Try this:

```
COUNT=$(sqlplus -s $USER/$PASS@proddb <<EOF
<snip>
EOF
)
```

The `$()` construct is usually safer (and easier to read).

Comment: Hi I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Getting error as `[YOU HAVE NEW MAIL]
In Checkcount
checkcount[13]: ~!@#$%^:  not found.
checkcount[13]: *-_{}:  not found.
checkcount[13]: ":/.,:  not found.

Nothing to Worry
You have mail in /usr/spool/mail/rbladmin`

Comment: Relevant code:
`function checkcount
{
echo "In Checkcount"
COUNT=`$(sqlplus -s $USER/$PASS@finratna <<EOF
set pagesize 0
set escape on
select count(*)
from tbaadm.htd
where cust_id is not null and
pstd_flg = 'Y' and
del_flg = 'N' and
tran_date =  (select db_stat_date-1 from tbaadm.gct) and
REGEXP_LIKE(tran_particular,'[^[:alnum:] ''`~!@#$%^&*-_{};":/.,<>?()]')
EOF)`
echo $COUNT
echo $COUNT | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' |& read -p COUNT1
}`

Comment: You still have to escape the special chars! (They look like they're not escaped in your comment: is this true?) The error message shows the line has been broken on `&`, `;`, `<` which all have special meaning for the shell.

Comment: Hi, I avoided the error by keeping the SQL query separate from the .sh file . Rather I called the SQL file @. So now it is working fine. Thanks for your comments although.